# How to extract code from a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this table that has these records

```
ID   **ExpLine**
1    0404079=0.00          
2    1444716<=0.00         
3    1.0<00226311 <= 0.00  
4    0001208 <= 0.00       
5    0.00<0243026<=2.00    
6    0036983 <= 0.00       
7    0036974=0.00
```

This table has ExpLine
which is a string that compares a code (made of numbers) and values

I want to extract that code in a separate column

like this

```
ID   **ExpLine**
1    0404079=0.00                -->            0404079
2    1444716<=0.00               -->            1444716
3    1.0<00226311 <= 0.00        -->            00226311
4    0001208 <= 0.00             -->            0001208
5    0.00<0243026<=2.00          -->            0243026
6    0036983 <= 0.00             -->            0036983
7    0036974=0.00                -->            0036974
```

The code is more than 4 numbers (5 +)

how can I extract that code?

Comment: You're looking for SUBSTR() and CHARPOS((). You can find information about them, as well as examples of how to use them, in the SQL Server documentation. I don't have a link, because I don't know what version you're using, but your favorite search engine should be able to find them.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL Server is 2016 or later, `STRING_SPLIT()` based solution is the best.

Otherwise, it is better to use *tokenization* instead of string parsing.

**DDL and sample data population**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, tokens NVARCHAR(256));
INSERT @tbl (tokens) VALUES
('0404079=0.00'),         
('1444716<=0.00'),
('1.0<00226311 <= 0.00'),
('0001208 <= 0.00'),
('0.00<0243026<=2.00'),    
('0036983 <= 0.00'), 
('0036974=0.00');  
-- DDL and sample data population, end
```

**SQL**

```
WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT t.ID, t.tokens, value AS result
        ,RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY LEN(value) DESC) AS seq
    FROM @tbl AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens,'<', @separator), SPACE(1),'') ) AS t2(token)
    CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(token, '=')
)
SELECT ID, tokens, result
FROM rs
WHERE seq = 1;
```

Check it out how to do it via XML and XQuery.  SQL Server 2014 or earlier.

Notable points:

- `CROSS APPLY` is tokenizing input string as XML.
- XQuery FLWOR expression is retrieving a token with length greater
  than 4.

For example, XML for the row where ID=3:

```
<root>
  <r>1.0</r>
  <r>00226311</r>
  <r />
  <r>0.00</r>
</root>
```

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = '=';

SELECT * 
    , c.query('
        for $x in /root/r/text()
        where string-length($x) gt 4
        return $x
').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(10)') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tokens,'<', @separator),SPACE(1),''), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | tokens | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0404079=0.00 | 0404079 |
| 2 | 1444716<=0.00 | 1444716 |
| 3 | 1.0<00226311 <= 0.00 | 00226311 |
| 4 | 0001208 <= 0.00 | 0001208 |
| 5 | 0.00<0243026<=2.00 | 0243026 |
| 6 | 0036983 <= 0.00 | 0036983 |
| 7 | 0036974=0.00 | 0036974 |

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the answer myself

I am using a function

```
declare @txt as varchar(100)
declare @t1 as varchar(100)
declare @t2 as varchar(100)
declare @t3 as varchar(100)
declare @t as varchar(100)
declare @n1 as int
declare @n2 as int

set @txt = '1.0<00226311 <= 0.00 '

set @txt = REPLACE(@txt, '<', ' ')
set @txt = REPLACE(@txt, '>', ' ')
set @txt = REPLACE(@txt, '=', ' ')

set @txt = trim(@txt)
set @n1 = CHARINDEX(' ',@txt)
set @n2 = LEN(@txt) - CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(@txt)) + 1

set @t1 = left(@txt, @n1)
set @t2 = SUBSTRING(@txt, @n1,@n2-@n1+1)
set @t3 = right(@txt, LEN(@txt) - @n2)

--SELECT @txt, @t1, @t2, @t3, @n1, @n2

if len(@t1) > len(@t2)
begin 
    set @t = @t1 
end
else
begin 
    set @t = @t2
end


if len(@t3) > len(@t)
begin 
    set @t = @t3
end

select @t
```

Comment: Inline function calls are notoriously slow. It is better to use set based implementation. Please check the other answer.